# Cufon Breaks when I add a product to my cart or other tasks which may somehow refresh the page

Tags: cufon

An example of the cufon breaking is when I add a product to my cart,

example here http://joemeetsjoy.com/products

When you click buy now then click ok on the pop up box the cufon breaks. It also happens if you go the the shopping cart and choose a shipping option.

Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: Please add code. People can't say why something happens if they can't see the underpinnings.

Comment: Hi I am not really sure which code to give you guys which would be helpful. As @Mark said it seems to be an ajax issue, however I have no idea what I could show you.

Answer (score 0):

I ran a Cufon.refresh() call, which restored the Cufon (running Chrome 15 on Mac) after clicking the "Buy Now" button (which did, as you say, "break the Cufon").

You may want to consider altering the behavior of the onClick handler of that button to run this function. A DOM update or reflow might be causing the Cufon to break as I noticed the onClick handler makes an AJAX call.

Comment: Thanks, however I can not alter the behavior of the onClick handler as this is a CMS and won't allow it. How do I use the Cufon.refresh()

Comment: Would it be something like this:

`<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
 Cufon.refresh();
});</script>`

Only that didnt seem to work

Comment: I believe your CMS is using Prototype (or a variation) to handle the AJAX calls, judging from the included Javascripts. I am not as familiar with Prototype, but check their [API](http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/Ajax/).

Comment: I ran it using the web inspector console in Chrome. Since there is a global *Cufon* object, you can arbitrarily run it whenever you want. You can insert some code to run this call, either on the element being clicked itself, or registering an event handler in a script tag somewhere to react to clicks on the those elements.